# Get detail Data From Adapter on android studio

Tags: java, android, adapter

I have  list data, then I want when I click one of item it'll show the detail but I don't know how to pass the data to detail activity.

So, how to make this? I've tried many ways of the available answers on Stack overflow, but all of them not working, or not related to my problem .

So, kindly help to do this.
[image: I want pass data to Detail Voucher activity]

here my adapter script :

```
public class VoucherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Voucher> {
    List<Voucher> mVoucherList;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    VoucherAdapter.ViewHolder holder;
    private Context context;


public VoucherAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Voucher> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    mVoucherList = objects;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new VoucherAdapter.ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_voucher, parent, false);
        holder.kode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtkode);
        holder.status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_stat);
        holder.expiredDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_tgl_exp);
        holder.list = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.itemListVoucher);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (VoucherAdapter.ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    holder.kode.setText(mVoucherList.get(position).getSerialNumber());
    holder.status.setText(mVoucherList.get(position).getStatus());
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mma");
    String reportDate = df.format(mVoucherList.get(position).getExpiryDate());
    holder.expiredDate.setText(reportDate);
            holder.list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(getContext(), VoucherDetailAktif.class);
                    context.startActivity(detailIntent);
                    //how to pass the data to detail activity?
                }
            });

    return v;

}

static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView kode;
    public TextView expiredDate;
    public TextView status;
    public RelativeLayout list;
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: typo, format and details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your custom model implements Parcelable, if not implement your class as Parcelable, and send like this,

```
Intent detailIntent = new Intent(getContext(), VoucherDetailAktif.class);
Voucher vouceher = mVoucherList.get(position);
detailIntent.putExtra("voucher", vouceher)
context.startActivity(detailIntent);
```

In your `VoucherDetailAktif.java` activity you can get the `Voucher` object like this,

```
Voucher vouceher = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("voucher");
```

If your Custom class implements `Serializable`, 
For sending data you can do same as above, but retrieving data in `VoucherDetailAktif.java` class you can do like this,

```
Voucher vouceherValue = (Voucher) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("voucher");
```

Note:

> add final to the position param in getView to access inside the
>   onClickListener

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```